# Last Logon Information Preventing Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: windows-7, login, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

Our recent changes enforced by our security department had me enable the following setting in our GPO:

```
Computer Configuration > Windows Components > Windows Logon > Display information on previous logons = Enable
```

Since then (more than 24 hours now) I am able to logon to the computers and servers locally but when I try to Remote Desktop to them I get the following message:

> "Security policies on this computer are set to display information about the last interactive logon. Windows could not retrieve this information. Please contact your network administrator for assistance."

I can't figure out how to be able to Remote Desktop back to the machines and servers. The system has the setting for Restricted Admin mode for Remote Desktop which was another setting we were supposed to enable but I am not sure if that is what is causing the problem.

Environments is 4  Windows Server 2008 R2 Servers. 9 Windows 7 Professional x64s all on the same domain.

Has anyone else run into this problem and know how to fix it?

**UPDATE 1:** I have a theory. Domain Controllers and computers have been applied. I have logged into the Domain Controller locally. But when I Remote Desktop to it I get the message.

My theory I am running on is the with Remote Restrict Administration Mode on it isn't passing the credentials as an interactive logon so it doesn't know what dates to show for what user.

Which would be a flawwwww in Windows Thinking if both setting were enabled.

Comment: Can you confirm your domain's functional level? From the GPO help text: "For domain user accounts in Windows Server 2003, Windows 2000 native, or Windows 2000 mixed functional level domains, if you enable this setting, a warning message will appear that Windows could not retrieve the information and the user will not be able to log on. Therefore, you should not enable this policy setting if the domain is not at the Windows Server 2008 domain functional level."

Comment: Also, make sure the GPO is applied to all domain controllers. See: https://serverfault.com/questions/938724/last-logon-error-when-logging-in-using-gpo-setting

Comment: @DougDeden Funcational level of the Domain is Server 2008 R2. And yes the GPO is applied to the Domain Controllers because when I log in to them locally I get the correct Last login information as stated in the information above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My theory has was correct in practice.

> My theory I am running on is the with Remote Restrict Administration
> Mode on it isn't passing the credentials as an interactive logon so it
> doesn't know what dates to show for what user.

Because Remote Restrict Administration mode does not send credential data over RDC, as it uses Anonymous creds to secure the connection. Because of that it does not invoke the lastlogin data from the domain controller to show you, and since it doesn't know who you are on RDC and can't show you that information it kicks you out.

Essentially the 2 settings can't be used in conjunction.